# Zend Framework 2 headscript

Tags: zend-framework2

It seems I remember that in Zend Framework, we could add styles/scripts via headScript in the action of a page. In Zend2, this doesn't seem to be an option.

I don't see much in the documentation about handling this.
Basically my question is; is it proper to add these styles/scripts in the view? Or is there there a new way to add them in the controller action?

Thanks

Comment: See the headScript() view helper -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#headscript-helper

Comment: Yes, I saw this... and I understand how it works in the layout, but what about adding scripts or styles to specific views? Is there a method available in the action? Should I just repeat this in the view? The documentation is not very clear.

Comment: Yes, the helper is available in views and layouts, I think the only caveat may be that you need to use prepend in views, but ymmv.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller action:

```
$this
    ->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('viewhelpermanager')
    ->get('HeadScript')
    ->appendFile('/js/custom.js')
;
```

You could make this easier by creating an "invokable"  "service locator aware" controller plugin.

You can do that in your modules config file:

```
...
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Head' => 'Application\Controller\Plugin\Head',
    )
),
...
```

Creating the "Head" class in `module/Application/src/Application/Controller/Plugin/Head.php` that implements `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` and build some methods like `javaScript()` or `styleSheet` for example that simply grab the view helper and return it:

```
return $this
    ->getServiceLocator()
    ->getServiceLocator() // Main service Locator
    ->get('viewhelpermanager')
    ->get('HeadScript')
;
```

Then in your controller it's more like:

```
$this->Head()->javaScript()->appendFile('/js/custom.js');
```

You could get as fancy as you wanted about it though. Maybe even Magento style with the XML governing the layout per action.

**UPDATE**

Output is buffered if you're using the ZF2 MVC. So i've found that adding scripts and stylesheets to a page is best done from the template file attached to your view model:

`$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/custom.js', 'text/javascript');`

`$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/custom.css');`

Keep it out of the controller since it is view related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't understand what about Marshall House talk.

Plugin need implements PluginInterface. Why implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface ?

Where paste this code?

```
return $this
->getServiceLocator()
->getServiceLocator() // Main service Locator
->get('viewhelpermanager')
->get('HeadScript');
```

Also AbstractPlugin (if extend from it) doesn't have getServiceLocator() methos. What it mean?
Main service Locator? Please write some example.

Comment: That would be the contents of a method like `javascript()` in the controller plugin.